# How to delete comment that is nested in Post schema with mongoose and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mern

I want to be able to delete comment that is inside my Post model.

This is my Schema for Post model:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    registration_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            text: String,
            userID: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

And I have this route:

```
router.delete('/comment/:id/:comment_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const postId = req.params.id
    const commentId = req.params.comment_id
}
```

comments in post looks like this:

```
 comments: [
     {
       _id: 5f1df4cf5fd7d83ec0a8afd8,
       text: 'comment 1',
       userID: 5efb2296ca33ba3d981398ff
     },
     {
       _id: 5f1df4d35fd7d83ec0a8afd9,
       text: 'commnet 2',
       userID: 5efb2296ca33ba3d981398ff
     }
   ]
```

I want to delete comment, and don't know how to do it. Does anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we find the post by `findByIdAndUpdate` then we delete the comment using `$pull` from the array of comments.

```
router.delete("/comment/:id/:comment_/id", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $pull: { comments: {_id:req.params.comment_id}},
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(400).send("Post not found");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: Nothing is deleted, i get same post with same comments

Comment: i fixed this, it should be like: ` $pull: { comments: {_id:  req.params.comment_id} }`, thanks for your help!